# Is parsing a CSV file in Node.js bad for performance or blocking?

Tags: node.js, csv

Being somewhat new to Node, I've read all over to be mindful of the event loop and careful not to block. I have a web application written in Node.js that has a feature allowing a user to upload a CSV file and save the data as a document in a MongoDB collection.

I've not been able to get a straight answer from anyone whether this is a bad idea. My concern is that if a user uploads a large file the application will become unresponsive for other users while each row of the file gets saved to Mongo.

Is my concern well-founded? Is there an established best practice here (i.e. use streams?) and what would you do if presented with this problem?

*Some background info*

- The files will be, on average, between 10kb - 100kb in size but a larger, 8mb file can happen (8mb is the server's max upload size).
- Using a different language **is an option** but only if there's a compelling reason to do so
- I have some Go daemons running with the application and planned to offload the CSV work to one of those or a new Ruby process if Node couldn't handle it. The only issue with this is sharing user sessions between the Node app and Go or Ruby process
- The production server has 2 CPU cores available to it so maybe blocking on one core is acceptable?

**Update:**

The implementation I'm using is the [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) Node module using streams in an Express app like this:

```
var csv = require('fast-cvs');
csv.fromPath('path/to/file.csv')
  .on('data', function(data) {
    // Save data to MongoDB
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    res.render('my_view', {});
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a well defined question.  It depends on implementation. A single asynchronous read of a few dozen lines from a file, with a callback that parses it and pushes it onto an array and then sets up the next async read/parse ought to be OK. Synchronous is possibly not ok.  A CSV reader could be written that way, but is the one you are using written that way... we don't know.  There are several contributed csv parsing modules.    Also, pushing the data out to a web browser can hide the issue that JSON.stringify() can also take time to convert 8MB of data.

Comment: I've added some detail to the question. I'm using the `fast-csv` module for parsing. It works with events and streams making me think this shouldn't be a problem but I'm a little ignorant of those topics so I'm wondering if this is as reliable and non-blocking as I think it is.

Comment: It looks like fast-csv emits a `'data'` event every time it reads a record (line). /Presumably/ it then queues up the next record's event in the event loop.  If that's the case, then you're good so long as your data event doesn't do something crazy.  I didn't wirte fast-csv nor have I read the code so I can't give an authoritative answer that it's written "right".  I always presume these things are written right if they're sufficiently popular.